# Match column A of sheet1 data with column A of sheet2 and pull all corresponding rows to sheet1 including duplicates

Tags: vba, macos, excel

My requirement is when a user entered data in columnA of sheet1 then it should look for a match in columnA of sheet2 if found then all the corresponding rows should be pulled to sheet1.In some cases for the entry in columnA of sheet1 there will be multiple matches in columnA of sheet2. In those scenarios i want all the duplicates data also to get pulled into sheet1.This required function is fullfilled with my following code.But i am facing few challenges as
1.For an example when three inputs are entered in ColumnA of sheet1, if only matches are found for only two inputs then they should be pulled to the corresponding rows of the input leaving the third input at last row.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6GXH.jpg)
2.The other challenge is When duplicates are found, all duplicates should be one next to each other before pulling data of other input.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhiGD.jpg)
3.When no match is found for any of the inputs should show match not found message box.
Below is the code which helped to some extent.

```
    Sub Getdata()
    Dim Ws1 As Worksheet, Ws2 As Worksheet, Ws3 As Worksheet
Dim vDB, vCr, vR()
Dim i As Long, k As Long, N As Long, j As Integer
Dim r As Long, C As Integer
Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
Set Ws1 = Sheets("MARSDATA")
Set Ws2 = Sheets("MARS")

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A3:A50")) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Not Found"
Exit Sub
End If

With Ws1
    r = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    C = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    vDB = .Range("A4", .Cells(r, C))
End With
With Ws2
    r = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    C = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    vCr = .Range("a1", .Cells(r, C))
End With

'vDB = Ws1.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
'vCr = Ws2.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
C = UBound(vDB, 2)
For i = 4 To UBound(vCr, 1)
    For k = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        If vCr(i, 1) = vDB(k, 1) Then
            N = N + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To C, 1 To N)
            For j = 1 To C
                vR(j, N) = vDB(k, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next k
Next i
With Ws2

lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    .Range(.Cells(lRow + 1, 1), .Cells(lRow + 1, lCol)).Resize(N, 26) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)

End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Have you looked for existing solutions for this on here? And on excel-vba and on superuser?

Comment: Yes, but didnt find any. The above code was also helped by YowE3K . I have made changes to my requirement but could not succeed.

Comment: Which question did YowE3K help with then? Where is it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48245783/copy-paste-including-duplicates

Comment: All I get is page not found - was it closed...

Comment: Yes , sorry it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I am more of a hack than a programmer, so this is a really dirty solution, but here is what I would do.

1. Do a search for the value and figure out where the data exists, if it does.
2. If it does, grab the data from that row.
3. Store the row number in a variable.
4. Step one cell down and do a new search.
5. If additional values are found, check to make sure that the row number isn't the same.  This would indicate that you'd looped through the data back to the start.

Repeat steps 4 and 5 until you get the original row number.